# How can I exclude the Path property from being indexed?

Tags: sharepoint

I have tried to exclude the Path property from being indexed from 
Shared Services->Search Administration->managed Properties->Crawled Properties.

I have un-checked the check box that says "Include values for this property in the search index". for all three: "Basic:11(Text), Basic:9(Text), Web:2(Text)" mappings.
I have reset the crawl contents, and done a full crawl.
Yet, when searching, the search service still return items where only the path matched my search text.

Is this the correct way of excluding the Path property?

**Update:**
The reason for excluding the Path is that when searching with IsDocument:1 in order to just search documents, and the keyword "orange" for example, SharePoint will return hits where the path contains the word "orange" even if the documents in that path doesn't contain the keyword in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand why you need to disable this? However, you cannot exclude the Path property as it is an integral part of Search and without it, the search results would not be linked. Keywords in the Path property (URL) is also an important factor in the relevance calculation.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But in a world where the customer specifies the functionality, and when the customer pays the bill, reasoning isn't always on top of the list. In a scenario where searching for documents _only_, it isn't always logical that SharePoint return hits on the Path.